# Where can I get a bank item to access my bank account on the go?

Tags: neverwinter

I always see in Neverwinter that people are using these portable mini banks as items right in front of them and they are never physically at a bank.

How can I get a portable bank item and where can I find them? Can I buy them? If so, who sells them and what kind of currency do I need in order to buy them?

Answer (score 5):

This is a Loyalty Rank 12 feature of the [VIP Program](https://www.arcgames.com/en/games/neverwinter/news/detail/9492533-neverwinter%3A-introducing-the-vip-program!) — meaning that it is only accessible after you have paid for 12 months of VIP access.  (By purchasing [VIP Packs](https://neverwinter.fandom.com/wiki/VIP_Program) from the Zen Store.)

> Summon banking portal: ability to use personal bank from anywhere. Anyone around will be able to use the bank.

So, yes, you can buy them.  The currency required is Zen, which you can acquire for Real World Money, or for Astral Diamonds on the Exchange (*lots* of Astral Diamonds — up to 750 per Zen), and it lasts for as long as your VIP status does.